# hash not defined for the UIColor UIPlaceholderColor need to first convert colorspace

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have an app that is written partially in Swift 3.2 and objective-c built with xcode 10, I am having a strange crash in some Swift ViewControllers, on the log that I collected, the line from that crash what is happening is that I am setting the text (valueLabel.text = "-") on a UILabel (the UILabel is a normal one no inheritance nor any customization).

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x212368ec4 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x211539a40 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x21226f594 -[NSCache init]
3  UIKitCore                      0x23f14fba0 (Missing)
4  UIKitCore                      0x23f14fc3c (Missing)
5  UIFoundation                   0x21c9ca778 attributeDictionaryHash
6  Foundation                     0x212dc8074 hashProbe
7  Foundation                     0x212ce5c24 -[NSConcreteHashTable getItem:]
8  UIFoundation                   0x21c975548 +[NSAttributeDictionary newWithDictionary:]
9  UIFoundation                   0x21c9778e4 -[_NSCachedAttributedString initWithString:attributes:]
10 UIFoundation                   0x21c9e5b98 __NSStringDrawingEngine
11 UIFoundation                   0x21c9697e4 -[NSString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:]
12 UIKitCore                      0x23f90c9a0 (Missing)
18 ole-consignado                 0x100e336ac $S14test_app18CardViewControllerC11resetLayout33_2E2D3FEF56CDB4998F73949398E4FE67LLyyF (CardViewController.swift:103)
19 ole-consignado                 0x100e327b4 $S14test_app18CardViewControllerC17viewWillDisappearyySbF (CardViewController.swift:73)
20 ole-consignado                 0x100e32804 $S14test_app18CardViewControllerC17viewWillDisappearyySbFTo (<compiler-generated>)
21 UIKitCore                      0x23ef39068 (Missing)
43 CoreFoundation                 0x2122f87cc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
44 CoreFoundation                 0x2122f3460 __CFRunLoopDoObservers
45 CoreFoundation                 0x2122f3a00 __CFRunLoopRun
46 CoreFoundation                 0x2122f31f0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
47 GraphicsServices               0x21456c584 GSEventRunModal
48 UIKitCore                      0x23f4fad40 (Missing)
49 ole-consignado                 0x100b37f74 main (main.m:14)
50 libdyld.dylib                  0x211db2bb4 start
```

So my question is any one has encountered that crash before and have a solution suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

An instance of UIPlaceholderColor is produced whenever you instantiate a UIColor via the `UIColor.init`, that takes no parameters. The thing about this is that it is completely valid in the semantics of UIKit, and leads to it being displayed as a `UIColor.clear`, probably.

The breaking point is an attempt to use it with CoreGraphics semantics. The underlying storage of the UIPlaceholderColor does not feature a color space and any color value storage, and for this reason, can not be converted to a CGColor using the `cgColor` getter. `hash` getter is the same story.

How do you resolve this situation? Identify, where exactly are you calling for `UIColor.init` and replace it with `UIColor.clear`, which will be easily convertible to CGColor.

Comment: This has been really useful. Thank you. I had some instances of UIColor() initialisation that did not cause any problems in ios13,* but would crash on ios12 inexplicably. You saved me time and effort 